# How to get attribute of a model saved in instance variable

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord, ruby-on-rails-3

I am writing a plugin, in which i define a new relation dynamically within plugin. Sample code is given below

```
module AttachDocumentsAs
   @as = nil
   def attach_documents_as(*attachment_as)
      attachment_as = attachment_as.to_a.flatten.compact.map(&:to_sym)
      @as           = attachment_as.first
      class_inheritable_reader(@as)

      class_eval do
          has_many @as, :as => :attachable, :class_name=>"AttachDocuments::Models::AttachedDocument"
          accepts_nested_attributes_for @as
      end 
   end
end
```

now in any model i used it as

```
class Person < AtiveRecord::Base
    attach_documents_as :financial_documents
end
```

Now want to access want to access this attribute of the class in overloaded initialize method like this

```
def initialize(*args)
   super(*args)
   "#{@as}".build 
end
```

But it is not getting required attribute, can any one help me in it. I want to build this relation and set some initial values.

Waiting for guidelines from all you guys.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're likely confusing the `@as` class instance variable, which is only available to class methods for Person, and the `@as` instance variable, which is only available to instances of this class. Even that explanation sounds a bit complicated, I know.

Each object has instance variables, and a class is simply a type of object. Instances of this class are also objects and they have their own independent instance variables. To get a class instance variable from an instance of a class you will need a reader method, like you've defined. Maybe what you mean is:

```
def initialize(*args)
  super(*args)

  # self.class.as returns something like :financial_documents, so use this method
  # to return a scope to build in.
  send(self.class.as).build
end
```

The way you're using `@as` suggests you're used to something like PHP or Perl where you can de-reference it like you might with `${$as}`. In Ruby you're usually de-referencing from a string or symbol into either a class, or a method.

It looks like you're trying to convert a symbol into a method call, and that's done through `send`.

If you were trying to convert a string into a class, you use the `constantize` method on String, a feature of the Rails environment.

Comment: I used 


class_inheritable_reader(@as)

class_inheritable_reader(:atd_as)
write_inheritable_attribute(:atd_as, @as)

and now inside initialize i can get it as

self.send(self.send(:atd_as))

but now the problem is to call the build on it

self.send(self.send(:atd_as)).build 

do not work.